# Scrolling tables horizontally without wrapping them in div

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

I wanted to enable horizontal scrolling on tables in my articles whenever their width exceeds the available width in webpage layout.

I tried to achieve this with CSS only, but failed, so I had to wrap all in a div using jQuery:

```js
$('table.data').wrap('<div class="tcontain" />');
```

Then I applied the following CSS:

```css
.tcontain {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This works but I want to avoid JavaScript. Please help!

Comment: It's hard to give you a solution without seeing your markup. Can you post an example fiddle or a link to your site?

Comment: @koala_dev and here is http://jsfiddle.net/bLyu6/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work in IE, not even IE9.

```css
table {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

**[Exaple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLyu6/3/embedded/result/)**

In the end, I think your JS solution would be the best if you want to avoid the hassle of changing the markup in your files.

Comment: Thanks! I agree I should keep the JS code. But your solution is best so far. Actually we wanted to enable smartphone users to scroll tables horizontally in narrow responsive design.

Comment: Note that you cannot specify any table-related properties for <table> element if you do this because technically it's no longer a table anymore. Spec compliant browsers will create phantom table element between the <table> element and the `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfooter>`.

Answer (score -1):

Give your table width 100%.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However this stretches small tables.

Comment: If you like give width to some value.